# How i replace the content between begin{document} and end{document}

Tags: livecode

How i replace the content between begin{document} and end{document}. while using my code the whole content are replaced.In below code i am using wordOffset but it's not working

```
on mouseUp
    put wordOffset("begin{document}",fld "MytextField") into tBegin 
    put wordOffset("end{document}",fld "MytextField") into tEnd
    put the htmlText of field "MytextField" into myHtml
    --put wordOffset("begin{document}",fld "myHtml") into tBegin
    --put wordOffset("begin{document}",fld "myHtml") into tEnd
     set the caseSensitive to true
     put the field SRText into myArrayToBe
     split myArrayToBe by CR
     --enable the field "SRText"
     --put "red,RED" & CR & "green,GREEN" & CR & "blue,BLUE" into myArrayToBe 
     --split myArrayToBe by CR
     put the number of lines of (the keys of myArrayToBe) into myArraylength
     repeat with i = 1 to myArraylength 
        --return i
        put  myArrayToBe[i] into y
        split y by colon
        put y[1] into searchStr
        put y[2] into replaceStr
        if searchStr is empty then
           put the  0 into m
        else 
           --put (word tBegin to tEnd of fld "MytextField")
           --put replaceText(word tBegin to tEnd of fld "MytextField","searchStr","good") into word tBegin to tEnd of fld "MytextField"
           put wordOffset("begin{document}",fld "MytextField") into tBegin 
           put wordOffset("end{document}",fld "MytextField") into tEnd
           --put holder into  myHtml
           --put replaceText(word tBegin to tEnd of fld "MytextField",searchStr,replaceStr)of fld "MytextField"
          replace searchStr  with  "<strike><font bgcolor=" & quote & "yellow" & quote & ">" & searchStr & "</font></strike><font bgcolor=" & quote & "green" & quote & ">" & replaceStr & "</font>" in myHtml

      end if
    end repeat
    --enable me
    set the htmlText of fld "MytextField" to myHtml

end mouseUp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use htmlText to both get and set the text, otherwise your offsets are off (e.g. if the first line of the field is bold, htmlText would give something like

```
<b>foo</b><br>begin{document}
```

whereas just 'fld "MytextField"' would give

```
foo
begin{document}
```

so offset("begin{document}",...) of the first gives 16, while for the second it gives 5. What I'd do is something like

```
put the htmlText of fld "MytextField" into theHTML
put offset("begin{document}", theHTML) into tBegin 
put offset("end{document}", theHTML) into tEnd
add length of "begin{document}" to tBegin
put character tBegin to tEnd of theHTML into textToChange

-- now do your search/replace on textToChange, not the field

put textToChange into character tBegin to tEnd of theHTML
set the htmlText of fld "MytextField" to theHTML
```

I use offset() here, which gives a character offset, but wordOffset as you had it should work, too, if you keep in mind that it gives you word numbers, so you'd have to replace `word tBegin to tEnd of theHTML`.

Comment: while using the code an error is appearing in the line "add length of "begin{document}" to tBegin"